# Creating ContentControls (RichText) in a loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to create several RichTextBoxes to an empty document in a loop, on different lines. For some reason I fail to do it.

So it should be like
contentcontrolone
{emptyline}
contentcontroltwo
{emptyline}
contentcontrolthree
{emptyline}
contentcontrolfour
{emptyline}

But it doesn't create the empty lines in between. This is the code I have so far:

Sub SetPlaceholderText()

```
Dim objCC As ContentControl

MoveToEnd

Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
objCC.Title = "ControlOneTitle"
objCC.SetPlaceholderText Text:="ControlOneText"
objCC.Tag = "ControlOneTag"

MoveToEnd

Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
objCC.Title = "ControlTwoTitle"
objCC.SetPlaceholderText Text:="ControlTwoText"
objCC.Tag = "ControlTwoTag"

MoveToEnd

Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
objCC.Title = "ControlThreeTitle"
objCC.SetPlaceholderText Text:="ControlThreeText"
objCC.Tag = "ControlThreeTag"

MoveToEnd

Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText)
objCC.Title = "ControlFourTitle"
objCC.SetPlaceholderText Text:="ControlFourText"
objCC.Tag = "ControlFourTag"

MoveToEnd
   End Sub

Sub MoveToEnd()
    Selection.TypeText Text:=vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
End Sub
```

I don't think it is *that* far from working, I just probably miss adding/selecting something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted a crucial argument when adding the content controls, the range where the content controls are to be added.

As you are working with the Selection object the quick fix would be:

```
ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, Selection.Range)
```

Working with the `Selection` object is not ideal for various reasons so a better method is to declare a range and work with that.

```
Sub SetPlaceholderText()

  Dim objCC As ContentControl
  Dim ccLocation As Range

  Set ccLocation = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range

  MoveToEnd ccLocation

  Set objCC = ccLocation.ContentControls.add(wdContentControlRichText)
  objCC.Title = "ControlOneTitle"
  objCC.SetPlaceholderText Text:="ControlOneText"
  objCC.Tag = "ControlOneTag"

  MoveToEnd ccLocation

  Set objCC = ccLocation.ContentControls.add(wdContentControlRichText)
  objCC.Title = "ControlTwoTitle"
  objCC.SetPlaceholderText Text:="ControlTwoText"
  objCC.Tag = "ControlTwoTag"

  MoveToEnd ccLocation

  Set objCC = ccLocation.ContentControls.add(wdContentControlRichText)
  objCC.Title = "ControlThreeTitle"
  objCC.SetPlaceholderText Text:="ControlThreeText"
  objCC.Tag = "ControlThreeTag"

  MoveToEnd ccLocation

  Set objCC = ccLocation.ContentControls.add(wdContentControlRichText)
  objCC.Title = "ControlFourTitle"
  objCC.SetPlaceholderText Text:="ControlFourText"
  objCC.Tag = "ControlFourTag"

  MoveToEnd ccLocation
End Sub

Sub MoveToEnd(ccLocation As Range)
  ccLocation.End = ccLocation.Paragraphs(1).Range.End
  ccLocation.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  ccLocation.InsertAfter vbCr & vbCr
  ccLocation.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End Sub
```